# What is Python common practice for stored procedure results

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, pymssql

I'm working on a project in Python that have to use stored procedures. In .NET I usually use Dapper and it stores the results in a **list of objects**.

In Python, as I understand, the common practice is to store the result as a DataFrame or a list of dictionaries.


But then, to access columns I'll have to write a string (res[***"SP_Col_Name"***]). So, in case I'll need to modify the result I'll have to look for the string (everywhere I wrote it) and change it (Instead of simply renaming object's field).


Finally, my question is: What is Python's common practice for retrieving stored procedure results and why?

Thanks a lot!

*I'm using MSSQL.

Comment: Can you not use Python to add a stored procedure's [`WITH RESULT SETS()`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2356/overview-of-with-result-sets-feature-of-sql-server-2012/) column names? (Also keep in mind that some stored procedures don't return results, and other stored procedures return multiple resultsets and they can have different shapes.) This doesn't solve the problem directly but it does give you a way to at least reduce the effort of refactoring (or motivation to do less refactoring). If a stored procedure returns `DoctorID, Name` how often are you changing those names in python?

Answer (score 1):

That's the difference between using an ORM like sqlalchemy, and using a lower-level API (here pyodbc/pandas).  As a middle ground you could create a class to contain all the column names in one place, and minimize the use of "magic strings" in your code.

```
class SP_Cols:
    SP_Col_Name= 'SP_Col_Name'
    SP_OtherCol_Name= 'SP_OtherColCol_Name'
```

Then write

```
res[SP_Cols.SP_Col_Name]
```